# My seed runs but I can not see the data on my table

Tags: javascript, postgresql, migration, knex.js, seeding

I'm relatively new to node and knex and I'm currently working on creating a database called g42beats_dev  in which I have a migration for a songs table. the migration looks as follow:

```js
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('songs', (table) => {
    table.increments('id').primary();
    table.integer('user_id').references('id').inTable('users').notNullable().onDelete('cascade');
    table.string('song_name').notNullable().defaultTo('');
    table.string('artist').notNullable().defaultTo('');
    table.timestamps(true,true);
  });
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('songs');
};
```

the migration happens fine. Here is an image: 
[image]

The problem is when I'm trying to seed the data. I wrote the following code to seed the data:

```js
exports.seed = function(knex, Promise) {
    // Deletes ALL existing entries
    return knex('songs').del()
        .then(function() {
            // Inserts seed entries
            return knex('songs').insert([
                {
                    id: 1,
                    user_id: 1,
                    song_name: 'Ode to Viceroy',
                    artist: 'Mac DeMarco',
                    created_at: new Date(),
                    updated_at: new Date()
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    user_id: 1,
                    song_name: 'Apocalypse Dreams',
                    artist: 'Tame Impala',
                    created_at: new Date(),
                    updated_at: new Date()
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    user_id: 14,
                    song_name: 'เพื่อนรัก',
                    artist: 'Parkinson',
                    created_at: new Date(),
                    updated_at: new Date()
                }
            ])
            .then(() => {
                return knex.raw("SELECT setval('songs_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM songs))");
            });
        });
};
```

after creating this I ran `knex seed:run songs` but that is not seeding the data.

can someone please provide some insight as to why this might be happening?  and maybe a way that I can accomplish the seeding of this data.
Thank you.

Comment: For those looking at this code. I was able to get this sorted out. It is super important to have your seeding files in order.  What helped me was to give each seed file a number in ascending order depending on how I created the files. Once I implementing these changes and ran `knex seed:run`   everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [KnexJS Migration With Associated Seed Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465443/knexjs-migration-with-associated-seed-data)